# Coloring svg elements depending on data value with d3.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

I was wondering how I could color svg rectangles depending on values from a dataset? If i was plotting rectangles for every data entry, how could I modify the color of the rectangle based on the data value?

so far I have:

```
         //Make an SVG Container
        var svgContainer = d3.select("body").selectAll("svg")
                                 .data(data)
                                 .enter().append("svg")
                                 .attr("width", 38)
                                 .attr("height", 25);

    //Draw the rectangle
     var rectangle = svgContainer.append("rect")
                    .attr("x", 5)
                     .attr("y", 5)
                     .attr("width", 38)
                     .attr("height", 25)
                      //want to color here based on data points, I want the data values to make my rectangles different shades of red
                    .style("fill", d3.rgb("red").darker(.data(data));
```

Let's say my data looks like:

var data = [{One:420, Two:222, Three:332},...]; And I only want the "Two" values to affect the color of the rectangles

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use some specific color code then below example will help.

- d3 color scale`d3.scale.category10()` contain 20 colors
- Create a pool of colors and use inside the code
- select the color based on the value

`var rectangle = svgContainer.selectAll("rect")
                .data(data).enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("x", function(d,i){ return 40*i})
            .attr("y", 5)
            .attr("width", 38)
            .attr("height", 25)
           .style("fill", function(d){ return d.Two <= 222 ? 'red' : 'green' });`

[Live Example](https://jsfiddle.net/caravinden/t8js9duc/)

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect:

```
    var svgContainer = d3.select("body").selectAll("svg")
                             .data(data)//INCORRECT
                             .enter().append("svg")
                             .attr("width", 38)
                             .attr("height", 25);
```

You are making as many svg's as the number of dataset.

It should have been:

```
 var svgContainer = d3.select("body")
   .append("svg")
   .attr("width", 38)
   .attr("height", 25);
```

To give color to rectangle:

```
//create a color scale
         var c10 = d3.scale.category10();
```

Now make as many rectangles as the dataset

```
     //Draw the rectangle
     var rectangle = svgContainer.selectAll("rect").data(data).enter().append("rect")
       .attr("x", 5)
       .attr("y", 5)
       .attr("width", 38)
       .attr("height", 25)
       //want to color here based on data points, I want the data values to make my rectangles different shades of red
       .style("fill", function(d){ return c10(d.One)});//use the color scale.
```

working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hgfw3nrr/2/)

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. When I do it this way, it only prints 1 rectangle as opposed to however many data entries there are.

Comment: nevermind, I got it. But now it prints all of rectangles the same color..I want it to print different colors depending on the value of the data entry

Comment: The color depends on your data's one value i have made anew fiddle to help you https://jsfiddle.net/hgfw3nrr/3/ if this answer your question you can accept it as answer here is how it works http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work